# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de actualizar un id concreto en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

Me estoy volviendo loco porque estoy intentando actualizar un `id` concreto de una tabla y no soy capaz de definir la variable en `laravel`.

Tengo una tabla de destacados con 7 líneas, porque la web solo tiene 7 destacados. Entonces la cuestión es que cada vez que se cambie un destacado se actualice esa línea.

```php
public function store(Request $request){

    $dest1=$request->destacadon1;//recibo el la noticia que va a pasar a ser destacada

    $destacado1=new Destacado::find(1);//falla aquí y no sé como decirle un id concreto

}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tienes un error, cambia tu línea:

```
$destacado1 = new Destacado::find(1);
```

por:

```
$destacado1 = Destacado::find(1);
```

*Eloquent* te devuelve el objeto resultante de la consulta (o *null* si no lo encuentra), no tienes que crear una instancia del modelo para realizar la búsqueda ya que estas llamando a un método estático del modelo Eloquent.

> **Nota:** la sintaxis `NombreClase::nombreMetodo()` se usa para llamar a
>   métodos estáticos de la clase, no se requiere crear previamente una
>   instancia de la misma.

Comment: Tu explicación esta errada en cuanto a teoría, no es necesario instanciar la clase porque el método `find` de la clase `Destacado` es estático y gracias a esto es posible acceder al método sin declarar un objeto.

Comment: Como comenta @AlbertHidalgo, sería excelente que actualizaras la respuesta dando la explicación del porqué no es necesario crear una instancia de la Clase. Eso enriquecería aún más la respuesta. Saludos